# What makes the SWAN wave model suitable for coastal regions?

Tags: waves, wave-modeling

It appears that the [SWAN wave model](http://www.swan.tudelft.nl/) is adept in shallow water and coastal regions. See for example [here](http://met.no/filestore/metno_report_18_2010.pdf) and [here](http://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/waves/nwps/). What makes SWAN more suitable in these regions than other wave models like WAVEWATCH? In checking the [feature list here](http://swanmodel.sourceforge.net/features/features.htm), I was not able to immediately find features that do not exist in other wave models.